# Name clash between package and class. Bug in Eclipse or javac?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, name-clash

For this source code ...

[image]

... Eclipse reports the following error:

> *Only a type can be imported. pkg.a resolves to a package*

... while Suns `javac` compiles it fine.

Similar situation if I try to fully qualify the class `pkg.a` like this:

[image]

Eclipse reports...

> *pkg.a cannot be resolved to a type*

... while Suns `javac` compiles it fine.

---

It seems like Eclipse favors interpreting an identifier as a package over a class name, while javac does the exact opposite. So, **is it a bug in Eclipse or in javac?**

(A reference to the language specification is obviously a plus.)

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely an Eclipse bug:

> [**6.4.2. Obscuring**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)
>
> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

The clear implication is that it is legal for a class and a package to have the same name.  Otherwise, the JLS would say that a class obscuring a package was illegal ... not that the class is used in preference.

---

Having said that, the only reason you've gotten into this situation is that you've chosen to ignore Java's conventions on naming.  Don't expect much sympathy ...

Comment: Do you know if this bug was already reported? In my case I'm depending on a library (JAR) that contains both a class (com.foo.Bar) and some resources in a folder that clash with class name (com/foo/Bar/boo.xml)
Here I don't think there is any naming convention violated... Still Eclipse can't compile that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a styling convention to give classes a name starting with a capital letter and packages with a lower case letter; that would solve your problem.

Comment: I did read the question; I consider your problem one of those things that only make life harder if you stand still on them since following a styling convention just avoids it.